# SQL query UPDATE two rows filtered by the other row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two rows that I want to UPDATE, the columns are `meta_key` and `meta_value`. The `meta_key` has two rows that I want to filter, it is the `first_name` and `last_name`. I want to update the `meta_value` but it is filtered by the `first_name` and `last_name`. My query is like this:

```
UPDATE 
  `wp_usermeta` 
SET 
  (`meta_value` = 'First Name' WHERE `meta_key` = 'first_name'), 
  (`meta_value` = 'Last Name' WHERE `meta_key` = 'last_name') 
WHERE `user_id` = (SELECT `user_id` FROM (SELECT MAX(`user_id`) AS `user_id`
FROM `wp_usermeta`) AS `reg`)
```

Please help me.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only needed one level of subselect.

```
UPDATE `wp_usermeta`
   SET `meta_value` = IF(`meta_key` = 'first_name', 'First Name',
                      IF(`meta_key` = 'last_name', 'Last Name',
                         `meta_value`))
 WHERE `user_id` = (SELECT MAX(`user_id`) FROM `wp_usermeta`)
   AND (`meta_key` = 'first_name' OR `meta_key` = 'last_name')
```

Alternatively, you can just use two separate queries as most people do.

```
UPDATE `wp_usermeta`
   SET `meta_value` = 'First Name'
 WHERE `user_id` = (SELECT MAX(`user_id`) FROM `wp_usermeta`)
   AND `meta_key` = 'first_name';
UPDATE `wp_usermeta`
   SET `meta_value` = 'Last Name'
 WHERE `user_id` = (SELECT MAX(`user_id`) FROM `wp_usermeta`)
   AND `meta_key` = 'last_name';
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just update in this fashion

```
UPDATE `wp_usermeta` 
SET `meta_value` = 'First Name' 
WHERE `meta_key` = 'first_name' 
  AND `user_id` = (SELECT `user_id` FROM (SELECT MAX(`user_id`) AS `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta`) AS `reg`)

UPDATE `wp_usermeta` 
SET `meta_value` = 'Last Name'
WHERE `meta_key` = 'last_name'
  AND `user_id` = (SELECT `user_id` FROM (SELECT MAX(`user_id`) AS `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta`) AS `reg`)
```